# Problem with running safe transaction service locally

Tags: gnosis-safe

**Hello !**
I tried to run a transaction service locally using this guides:

- [Run safe infrastructure locally](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/running_locally.md);
- [Setup chain info](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/chain_info.md).
  I ran all the commands and set up the chain with the following settings:

```json
{
 "chainId": "43113",
 "chainName": "Avalanche Fuji Testnet",
 "shortName": "avax",
 "description": "",
 "l2": true,
 "rpcUri": {
   "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
   "value": "https://api.avax-test.network/ext/C/rpc"
 },
 "safeAppsRpcUri": {
   "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
   "value": "https://api.avax-test.network/ext/C/rpc"
 },
 "publicRpcUri": {
   "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
   "value": "https://api.avax-test.network/ext/C/rpc"
 },
 "blockExplorerUriTemplate": {
   "address": "https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/{{address}}",
   "txHash": "https://testnet.snowtrace.io/tx/{{txHash}}",
   "api": "https://api-testnet.snowtrace.io/api?module={{module}}&action={{action}}&address={{address}}&apiKey={{apiKey}}"
 },
 "nativeCurrency": {
   "name": "Avalanche",
   "symbol": "AVAX",
   "decimals": 18,
   "logoUri": "/media/chains/43113/currency_logo.png"
 },
 "transactionService": "http://nginx:8000/txs",
 "vpcTransactionService": "http://nginx:8000/txs",
 "theme": {
   "textColor": "#ffffff",
   "backgroundColor": "#000000"
 },
 "gasPrice": [],
 "ensRegistryAddress": null,
 "recommendedMasterCopyVersion": "1.3.0",
 "disabledWallets": [],
 "features": []
}
```

Then I configured the webhooks by this address:
http://localhost:8000/txs/admin
with following values:

- http://nginx:8000/cgw/v1/chains/43113/hooks/events
- Basic some_random_token

But when i try to create safe, i saw errors in my console:
[image]

with error code = 1337
[image]

[image]

Then i am back to main page and saw more errors in console:
[image]

And when i try to select my wallet, i saw these errors:
[image]
[image]

In the last case, we see that chainid === 43114 instead chainid === 43113 somehow.
But i have only one chain.
**What is going on?)))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hi there!

Looks like I solved this problem myself!

The problem was in:

- Invalid setting of **shortName** parameter in chain settings. You need to use the values from the [Eip-3779 page](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/protocol-kit/src/utils/eip-3770/config.ts);
- You need to add addresses of smart contracts of **master copies** and **proxy factories** on the configuration page. Addresses can be found [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/blob/master/gnosis/safe/addresses.py).

Also, I recorded a detailed [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUytj_xStDI) on setting up the service for Avalanche Fuji C-Chain.

Answer (score 0):

We are not the **Safe community**, but I can provide some guidance.

It appears that your node configuration might be incorrect. Please use the official Avalanche website's settings for the Fuji Testnet:

```
Network Name: Avalanche Fuji C-Chain
RPC URL: https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc
ChainID: 43113
Symbol: AVAX
Explorer: https://testnet.snowtrace.io/
```

Also, double-check the `"l2": true` value in your configuration, make these changes and see if the errors are resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  
But it doesn't seem to work in my case.  

I replaced `https://api.avax-test.network/ext/C/rpc` to `https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc` but nothing changed.

Comment: And interestingly, the page is still trying to access chain 43114 at the same time as 43113.

Browser console:    

GET  http://localhost:8000/cgw/v1/chains/43113/safes/0x36FdDf45f89d7Cf265891578734Ac410685D03a1/transactions/queued 404

GET http://localhost:8000/cgw/v1/chains/43114/owners/0x58Dc259b055Ea0d800f7856900945F95F260218E/safes 404

react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Code 610: Error fetching safes by owner (1337: {"detail":"Not found."})